# How to collect leap motion hand information and sent it to iPhone?

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am trying to develop a Unity project with leapmotion and iPhone, and Currently I have came up with a problem which is how to collect leap motion hand information. Like the location of the hands. There is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nu9lzzVj8iY&t=8s) on the YouTube showing that it is possible to implement leapmotion with iPhone.

Can anyone help with that.

Comment: You need to have some client/server interaction. Leapmotion sends information to the server. The server sends that same information to the iPhone client. You would need to create a custom iPhone app that handles this information. The video you linked does exactly this here: https://youtu.be/nu9lzzVj8iY?t=31s

Comment: @bpgeck Do you know some tutorials related with how to send leapmotion information to the server?

Comment: You would be setting up the server yourself. Since you're using Unity you would probably make it in C#. You would also choose how you want the leap motion information be sent to your server. Essentially you choose some sort of standard and handle sending and receiving messages accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution I try to implement is I use C++ API to collect all the hand information and send it to iPhone through Bluetooth. It is also possible to communicate iPhone with WIFI. Hope that helps.

Finally, I use C# socket communication to implement it. And I success. I post the solution in my blog. Hope can help. 
http://hanslen.me/blog/index.php/2017/01/06/leap-motion-brings-gesture-control-to-iphone/

If you have any other questions, leave a comment in my blog.